# Xcode 7 code coverage littering project directory with GCDA files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, code-coverage, xcode7

I'm running my unit tests in Xcode 7 for the first time, after refactoring my Swift code for 2.0 and fixing all of the various new compiler warnings and errors. I'm seeing a few different behaviors, though, which are probably all related.

1. As the unit tests conclude, I get a `gcda` file for each system framework I link against dumped into my project root directory (e.g. `QuartzCore.gcda`, `CoreData.gcda`)
2. I get a long list of the following errors:

   > < project root >/CoreGraphics.gcda: cannot merge previous GCDA file: corrupt arc tag (0x00000017)
3. Finally, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception thrown, with this stack trace:

   ```
   #0  0x0000000105cf06b4 in llvm_gcda_emit_function ()
   #1  0x0000000105845c0a in __llvm_gcov_writeout ()
   #2  0x0000000105cf18e4 in llvm_writeout_files ()
   #3  0x00007fff9641271b in __cxa_finalize_ranges ()
   #4  0x00007fff96412a30 in exit ()
   #5  0x0000000100056e9f in ___XCTestMain_block_invoke ()
   #6  0x000000010000e7c9 in -[XCTestDriver _runSuite] ()
   #7  0x000000010000f31a in -[XCTestDriver _checkForTestManager] ()
   #8  0x0000000100056c69 in _XCTestMain ()
   #9  0x0000000100001dc9 in ___lldb_unnamed_function3$$xctest ()
   #10 0x00007fff9098d5c9 in start ()
   #11 0x00007fff9098d5c9 in start ()
   ```

I have **Enable Code Coverage Support** and **Generate Legacy Test Coverage Files** turned on, though I've tried toggling the latter and it made no difference. I'm using Xcode 7.1 on OS X 10.10.5.

Turning on **Gather coverage data** for the scheme *appeared to fix #3*, but then it came back.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 7.1.1, it might be a bug of `__gcov_flush()`. I hook it and fix it as follow:

1. In the file that calls `__gcov_flush()`, replace the `extern void __gcov_flush(void);` with `#import “GCDAProfiling.h”`.
2. Then drag this file to your Xcode project: `GCDAProfiling.c`, `GCDAProfiling.h`, `InstrProfilingUtil.c`, `InstrProfilingUtil.h` from https://github.com/liuslevis/GCDACorruptionFix
3. build and run.

I add function `skip_special_file()` and `adding overflow protection` to file `GCDAProfiling.c`. Xcode does not crash anymore, and the counting of line of code recovered by command `lgcov` from `.gcda` file seems to be non-zero.

Ref.: http://davidlau.me/2015/12/05/Trying-to-fix-Xcode-7-GDCA-file-corruption/

Comment: The page linked to is also tough to read, since it's apparently bilingual, alternating between an Asian language and English. It would be super helpful if you could summarize it in your answer.